# RecursionError while trying to implement a function recursively

Tags: python

I need to implement a recursion function which will provide the first N elements of a sequence, `x_{n+1} = r*x_n*(1-x_n)`. The code I present below is not running, the error being  `if N == 0: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. I will appreciate your help in making the code run.

```
def sequence(N, x0, r):
    A = [x0]
    if N == 0:
        return x0
    else:
        A.append(r * sequence(N, x0, r) * (1 - sequence(N, x0, r)))
    return [A[i] for i in range(N + 1)]


print(sequence(10, 2, 2))
```

Comment: You always pass `N` as-is to the recursive calls of `sequence()`, so there's no way you could ever reach `if N == 0` if you originally pass in a non-zero `N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying as close as possible from your initial try, I would do something that also returns a sequence, not a number

```py
def sequence(N, x0, r):
   A=[x0]
   if N==0:
      return A
   else:
      return A + sequence(N-1, r*x0*(1-x0), r)

print(sequence(10, 2, 2))
```

Explanation: it computes the first element of the sequence, and then the rest of it, recursively.

Just trace it for a few values.

### For N=0

Simple, it just returns `[x0]`

### For N=1

For clarity (otherwise, x0 means different things during recursions), let's choose x0 for the initial call=2, and also (even if r stays the same thorough all call), choose r=3. So let's call `sequence(1,2,3)`

- In `sequence(1,2,3)` call, we starts by `A=[2]`
- Then, since N≠0, we go to else, so we compute `A=[2]+sequence(0,3*2*(1-2),3) recursively, that is` sequence(0,-6,3)``

  - In this `sequence(0,-6,3)` call, we starts with `A=[-6]`
  - Since N=0 in this call, we simply return A, aka `[-6]`
- So, back in `sequence(1,2,3)`, we return A+result of recursive call `sequence(0,-6,3)`. That is `A+[-6]`. That is `[2]+[-6]`
- so final answer is `[2, -6]`

### For N=2

(And still initial x0=2, and r=3)

- In `sequence(2,2,3)` call, we start with `A=[2]`
- Since N=2≠0, we return `A+sequence(N-1,r*x0*(1-x0), r)`, and for that we need to compute `sequence(1, -6, 3)` recursively

  - In `sequence(1,-6,3)` call, we start with `A=[-6]`
  - Sine N=1≠0, we return `A+sequence(N-1,r*x0*(1-x0),r)` that is `[-6] + sequence(0, 3*(-6)*7, 3)` = `[-6] + sequence(0, -126, 3)`.
  - so we have to call recursively `sequence(0, -126, 3)`.

    - In `sequence(0, -126, 3)`, we start we `A=[-126]`
    - Since N=0, we just return that `[-126]`
  - now back in `sequence(1,-6,3)` call. Our `[-6]+sequence(0,-126,3)` computation `[-6]+[-126]` or `[-6, -126]`, which is what we return
- now back in `sequence(2, 2, 3)` call. Our `[2]+sequence(1,-6,3)` computation is therefore `[2]+[-6,-126]` or `[2,6,-126]`. Which is our final answer

Note that no redundant computation is done here. And it stays as close as possible from your initial answer.

Another, more "functional" recursion, which for the record, was my previous main answer (what is now my main answer was 1st provided as an alternative solution, before I realized it was probably the one your are expected to provide)

```py
def sequence(N, x0, r):
    if N == 0:
        return [x0]
    else:
        prev=sequence(N-1, x0, r)
        prev.append(r * prev[-1] * (1-prev[-1]))
        return prev
```

It is also recursive, and efficient. But not as elegant. I mean, the recursion here is just a way to repeat N times the `prev.append(...)` line. We could have achieved the same result by iterating N times that line with a for loop. So recursion brings nothing. Whereas in the first solution, it has the advantage to stick to mathematical recurrent definition of the sequence (that is one advantage of recursion. It may be harder to understand for computer scientist used to imperative programming. But for a mathematician, it is closer to the way we define sequences)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might want

```
def compute_value(N, x0, r):
    if N == 0:
        return x0
    x_n = compute_value(N - 1, x0, r)
    return r * x_n * (1 - x_n)


sequence = [compute_value(n, 2, 2) for n in range(10)]

print(sequence)
```

This prints out

```
[2, -4, -40, -3280, -21523360, -926510094425920, -1716841910146256242328924544640, -5895092288869291585760436430706259332839105796137920554548480, -69504226188572366382469893394830651557109425404264568995802412215018036314883217970500884577054804760905832770274449717760, -9661674916144457552727034361009790527700732880801664275092268814451233373207768500008969714893014677195041164647293059752576754550666470442049020239364319771280275066863699741389031161203686169060521699834121138295895752329492941497636218270720]
```

(boy, those are some big negative numbers...)

Comment: This is quite inefficient.

Comment: @BlackBeans Yes. It can be made efficient by adding the `@cache` decorator to `compute_value`. ;-)

Comment: Yes. That is the logistic sequence. It is supposed to be used with initial values between [0,1]. It has a fascinating behavious, depending on value of r. If r<1, it converges toward 0. If 1<r<3 it converges but not toward 0. If 3<r<3.56 it doesn't converge strictly speaking, but oscillate between 2, 4, 8, ... limits. Over 3.56, it is pure chaos. And in complex space, the area of r for which the sequence is chaotic is (ignoring a simple geometric transformation) Mandelbrot's fractal.

Comment: Oh, and also, it is a simple modelisation of a pandemic evolution, r, being the same "R" parameter we always hear about in pandemic talk.

Comment: Thanks. How you will do that with `@cache` to make it more efficient ?

Comment: @user996159 literally add `@cache` before `compute_value`, after importing it from `functools` (ie. `from functools import cache`).

Comment: Thanks. In what sense makes it the code more efficient  ? I used it, I do not see any difference in the speed of finding the sequence. For `N = 20`, it starts already to get very slow in finding the sequence with or without `@cache`.

Comment: @user996159 With `@cache`, the result for a given computation is memoized, so future calls won't need to recurse at all.

Comment: Also, if `@cache` doesn't seem to make a difference, you've probably applied it wrong somehow. A quick benchmark with `timeit`: `name='nocache' iters=10 time=0.915 iters_per_sec=10.93` / `name='w/cache' iters=10000000 time=0.562 iters_per_sec=17793958.42`

Comment: I simply added `from functools import cache` and `@cache` before the function that you defined. Is it as simple as that?

Comment: Yes. Of course you'll notice the speedup only after the second invocation - there's no way around having to actually do the maths once.